# Javascript code executed before css is downloaded and parsed

Tags: css, asynchronous, preload, lighthouse

I was reading about async scripting in web apps i came across with this article. In a nutshell, it says that javascript scripts dont get executed until all stylesheet css are downloaded and parsed. So i tried to test this for myself with a small example.

As you can see in the perfomance report, jquery script executes just fine by itself and afterwards, css is downloaded and parsed.

Can someone explain why have this behaviour?

> Because of this, CSS may block parsing depending on the order of
>   external style sheets and scripts in the document. If there are
>   external style sheets placed before scripts in the document, the
>   construction of DOM and CSSOM objects can interfere with each other.
>   When the parser gets to a script tag, DOM construction cannot proceed
>   until the JavaScript finishes executing, and the JavaScript cannot be
>   executed until the CSS is downloaded, parsed, and the CSSOM is
>   available.

[source](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/09/building-the-dom-faster-speculative-parsing-async-defer-and-preload/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>


    <link rel="preload" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" as="style" href='https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/welcome.b2b.test/form/bundle.css'/>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"/>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        console.log("window");
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking why someone would want to run JS before CSS?

Comment: Im saying that the article says that js executes always after css is parsed. I dont see this behaviour here

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don’t see that behavior here is because the CSS file isn’t passed as a parsable results, you’ve preloaded the asset but not made registered as CSS so your CSS will run after the JS but when it become a style sheet it will block the thread at that time.

Comment: There is no css options pass to preload. Also, the issue was that i had cache disbled in dev tools